# Changing main nib file base name, executable name and updating app

Tags: ios, ipad, nib

My app's 1.0 version has "main nib file base name" set to MainWindow in plist file. Now in 2.0 I have changed it to MyMainWindow & renamed the MainWindow.xib to MyMainWindow.xib.

When our users update our app to 2.0. is MainWindow.nib will still remain inside app bundle and also a new file MyMainWindow.xib will be copied ? Is there any problem with this ? I hope iOS will now load MyMainWindow.xib and not MainWindow.xib even if it will be there.

Generally I want to know all the older files inside app bundle will remain there after update or everything get replaced ? When I executed my app 2.0 from within XCode over 1.0 installed from App store I can see both the nib files inside .app folder. I used [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) to check files.

Another change is the executable (and bundle display) name. E.g. in 1.0 app1 now it is app2. Will it create any problem on update ?

After changing app exe name when I executed my app 2.0 from within XCode over 1.0 installed from App store app is crashing on launch.
Here is the console log

> Jul 12 16:17:36 unknown com.apple.launchd[1](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) :
>   (UIKitApplication:com.myapp[0x8e12])
>   posix_spawn("/var/mobile/Applications/FFF6DFCF-F641-4E04-8774-71A2A3619BD9/myapp.app/app2",
>   ...): Permission denied Jul 12 16:17:36 unknown SpringBoard[15]
>   : Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 2401:
>   (os/kern) failure Jul 12 16:17:36 unknown com.apple.launchd[1](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)
>   : (UIKitApplication:com.myapp[0x8e12]) Exited with code: 1
>   Jul 12 16:17:37 unknown SpringBoard[15] : Unable to send
>   activation event to  com.myapp
>   animate statusBarOrientation = 2  activate: safe animationStart = 0 
>   deactivate: : (ipc/send) invalid destination port Jul 12 16:17:37
>   unknown SpringBoard[15] : Application 'app2' exited
>   abnormally with exit status 1

Although, after crash if I run again from XCode, it executes successfully (not sure on 2nd run or 3rd run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when i updated the app using [testflight](https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/) everything worked correctly as expected. I have changed the bundle display name as well executable name and after update old bundle app1.app was removed and app executed normally.